# How to rename directory from all user accounts

Tags: bash, command-line

Let say that more users have a `tmp` directory in their home directory. I want to rename each `tmp` directory in each user home directory. What is the easiest way?

Something like this:

```
sudo mv /home/*/tmp /home/*/temp
```

is not ok.

And something like this:

```bsh
for dir in /home/*; do
    if [ -d $dir/tmp ]; then
        mv $dir/tmp $dir/temp
    fi
done
```

seems too much.

Comment: Why is the second option "too much"? By the way, it should be `mv "$dir/tmp" "$dir/temp"` in case a home directory has a space in its name. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @JosephR. Well, looking for something shorter if possible. Something wrong if? And let's exclude the case with space (I'm not interested in).

Comment: I've come up with a fancy oneliner: `for dir in /home/*; do if [ -d "$dir/tmp" ]; then mv "$dir/tmp" "$dir/temp"; fi; done`

Comment: @Sammitch You can do shortest: `for d in /home/*; do if [ -d "$d/tmp" ]; then mv "$d/tmp" "$d/temp"; fi; done` :)

Comment: What should your script do if the user already has a directory named `~/temp`? What if there's a file with that name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl comes with a `rename(1)` command that is installed on most Linux systems. On Debian-based systems it is in `/usr/bin` and for this case, you would use it like this:

```
$ rename 's/tmp$/temp/' /home/*/tmp
```

The first argument is a perl expression that acts on the subsequent arguments generating a new name. Each is then renamed according to the result of that expression.

If a home directory already has a file/directory called `temp`, you'll just get an error for that directory and `rename` will continue:

```
/home/c/tmp not renamed: /home/c/temp already exists
```

You can run it first with the `-n` flag to see what rename would do without actually doing it and make sure it all looks right. Then drop the `-n` and let it do its job.

Comment: Mind: blown. Once again, Perl to the rescue :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of for shortening the second option in your question is:

```
for dir in /home/*;do
    [ -d $dir/tmp ] && mv -n $dir/t{,e}mp
done
```

but this does away with readability somewhat. Note that `t{,e}mp` is expanded by the shell into the two words `tmp` and `temp`. So the command line would be expanded to `mv <contents of $dir>/tmp <contents of $dir>/temp`. In general, the shell expands `prefix_{a,b,c}_suffix` to `prefix_a_suffix prefix_b_suffix prefix_c_suffix`. An empty position such as the first one in `{,e}` is expanded into an empty string.

You can also do something similar with `perl`:

```
perl -e '
    @a=grep {-d} glob "/home/*/tmp";
    map { rename $_ => $_=~ s/tmp\Z/temp" } @a
'
```

but I still maintain that your original version was good enough.

**Edit**

Added the `-n` switch to `mv` to guarantee it won't clobber `$dir/temp` if it exists as noted in Michael Kjörling's comment on the question. The Perl version *will* clobber `temp` if it exists.

Comment: Ok, it's shorter, I'll give you +1. But can you explain what means `t{,e}mp`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo find /home -maxdepth 2 -type d -name 'tmp' -execdir mv {} temp \;
```

Here, `maxdepth` ensures that you look only upto two levels from the current directory. And, `execdir` specifies that the subsequent command will be executed by changing to the location where the found file is.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007149/147021

Comment: This would also rename files called `tmp`. You might want to add `-type d`.

Comment: Joseph R. Thanks, yet again! Just forgot while testing :)

Comment: One more thing to note is that, according to the link you cited, `-execdir` works for GNU `find` only.

Comment: i'd rather check the file /etc/passwd for the real user's homedir. /home maybe the standard, but this script woudn't work for user home-dirs which are organised into subfolders or something similar.

Comment: @JosephR. `-execdir` is a relatively recent addition to GNU find (2005). It comes from BSDs (1996 in OpenBSD)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

If your system has a getent command and a `mv` that accepts a `-T` option, you could do:

```
getent passwd |
  while IFS=: read -r x x uid x x home x; do
    [ "$home" = / ] ||
    [ "$home" = /var ] ||
    [ "$uid" -lt 500 ] ||
    [ ! -d "$home/tmp" ] ||
    find "$home/tmp" -prune -user "$uid" -exec sh -xc '
      mv -T -- "$1" "${1%/*}/temp"' sh {} \;
done
```

That is, we list the user database to retrieve uid and home directory. We rule out those users that have `/` or `/var` as their home directories (as we don't want to rename `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`) and users whose uid is below 500 (as on most systems, those are system users).

Then we only consider `$home/tmp` if its owner is the user in question (again to avoid moving the wrong file/dir).

The `-T` option as found in GNU mv is in case `$home/temp` already existed, to avoid moving `tmp` inside it.

Note that any failure of `mv` will generate an error message, but the failure exit status will be lost.

Comment: Not to criticize your (characteristic) juggernaut, there, but I believe the OP's intent was to _shorten_ their (already very short) loop. :)

Comment: @JosephR. - yes we always learn something new every time he posts a solution 8-)

Comment: @slm Agreed. The above snippet is definitely "ready for prime-time" and I _did_ learn at least 3 new things from it. I just think it's probably overkill in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a more compact version of your for loop you can do it slightly more compact like so:

```
$ for dir in /home/*/tmp; do [ -d $dir ] && mv $dir ${dir/%tmp/temp/};done
```

This will use bashes globbing facility to find all the directories and files that match the regular expression `/home/*/tmp`. It then tests to see whether it's a directory or not, if it's a directory, then move it. The last bit `${dir/%tmp/temp/}` does a search and replace on the contents of variable `$dir` and replaces `tmp` with `temp`. This search & replace is done only once from right to left, thus protecting anything beyond the `tmp` directory.

#### Example

Say I have this fake directory structure:

```
$ tree -p
.
`-- [drwxrwxr-x]  home
    |-- [drwxrwxr-x]  sam1
    |   `-- [drwxrwxr-x]  tmp
    |-- [drwxrwxr-x]  sam2
    |   `-- [drwxrwxr-x]  tmp
    |-- [drwxrwxr-x]  sam3
    |   `-- [drwxrwxr-x]  tmp
    `-- [drwxrwxr-x]  sam4
        `-- [-rw-rw-r--]  tmp
```

Now if we use a modified version of our command from above which simply echoes out the `mv` command rather than run it we can see what it's going to do:

```
$ for dir in home/*/tmp; do [ -d $dir ] && echo "mv $dir ${dir/%tmp/temp/}";done

mv home/sam1/tmp home/sam1/temp/
mv home/sam2/tmp home/sam2/temp/
mv home/sam3/tmp home/sam3/temp/
```

**NOTE:** The beginning `/` is intentionally not there so that I could run this test from a sample directory I setup.

#### rename instead of mv

You could also enlist the help of the command `rename` instead of `mv`. This changes the example slightly:

```
 $ for dir in /home/*/tmp; do [ -d $dir ] && rename $dir ${dir/%tmp/temp/};done
```

Comment: What if one of the user's home directories had the letters `tmp` in it?

Comment: @JosephR. - hmm...I can change the regex so that it replaces /tmp/ instead. Thanks!

Comment: A question: is there a specific reason you prefer `[ ! -d $dir ] || mv` to `[ -d $dir ] && mv`?

Comment: @JosephR. - no, just the way I was thinking about it. If not a dir. then skip it. I tend to think that way for some reason. I generally like to code to the thing I'm excluding rather than the thing I'm looking for. Not sure if that's a bad habit or what, just something I've noticed that I do. I think you've made me more attentive that I'm doing it 8-). It might be because when you're doing shell work you're often times trying to remove cruft from one pipe to the next.

Comment: @JosephR. - I went with this instead `${dir/%tmp/temp/}`. Will only replace the right most occurrence of `tmp`. Also flipped the logic around per your feedback. Thanks for the critique 8-).

Comment: I wasn't critiquing, I was simply wondering if the inverted logic had an advantage I wasn't aware of. It's interesting that Stephane's answer also has the same inverted logic; looks like it's a common thinking pattern. :)

Comment: @JosephR. - That's a compliant any time you do something the same as him 8-). BTW I liked your use of the `t{,e}mp`. I can never remember to use that abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

Produce the move statements and evaluate them in one shot:

```
ls -d /home/*/tmp | sed 's/.*t/mv &mp &e/' | sh -xv
```

Comment: I think you meant `mv &mp &emp` inside your `sed` command. Also [don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: No, `mv &mp &e` works just fine.  Try it.